# Segmentation fault in a for loop

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault for this code and I can't, for the life of me, figure out why. I'm rather new to pointers so it could be something obvious. The code is supposed to take two lines of integers from stdin and print them out in an alternating fashion. I haven't finished the last part of the code which prints out the alternating numbers.

```
    int main(){
        char *str1 = NULL;
        char *str2 = NULL;
        size_t sz = 0;
        int i;
        int x;
        char *rp1 = NULL;
        char *rp2 = NULL;
        getline(&str1, &sz, stdin);
        getline(&str2, &sz, stdin);
        char *result1;
        result1 = malloc(sizeof(*str1));
        char *result2; 
        result2 = malloc(sizeof(*str2));
        for(i = 0; (x = sscanf(str1, "%s ", &result1[i])) > 0; i++){
            if(x == EOF){
               return 0;
            }
            if(!isdigit(result1[i])){
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid non-integer input\n");
               return 1;
            }
        }
        rp1 = malloc(i);
        rp1 = result1;
        for(i = 0; sscanf(str2, "%s ", &result2[i]) > 0; i++){
            if(!isdigit(result2[i])){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid non-integer input\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        rp2 = malloc(i);
        rp2 = result2;
        return 0;
  }
```

When I run gdb, it says I'm getting the segmentation fault at line 25, which is the first for loop.

Edit: So I've fixed one issue which was in the malloc function before the for loops, but I'm still getting the segmentation fault.

Comment: When you ran it under your debugger, which line generated the segfault?

Comment: Yeah woops sorry I was adding that right when you replied. gdb says line 25, which is the first for loop.

Comment: if str1 is a pointer, why are you trying to malloc the size of a pointer?  Shouldnt you malloc the size of what it is pointing to?

Comment: What do you think this is doing: `malloc(sizeof(str1));` ?

Comment: 'result1 = malloc(sizeof(str1));' does not do what you seem to think it does:(

Comment: Ah yes i've been changing that line over and over. Should it be the dereferenced pointer in the malloc function or does that not work either?

Comment: `sizeof(*str1)` is most likely 1 because `*str1` is a `char`, which is typically one byte. What you actually want is `strlen(str1)+1` (add 1 to account for the null terminator)

Comment: `result1` and `result2` should be `char**` if you want to store multiple strings in them, and you will need to allocate each element of them before you can use it.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not concatenation per say,  I'm reading individual values from each line and outputting them one by one and alternating the lines. So an input of "12 13 14" and "1 2 3" would ouput "12 1 13 2 14 3"

Comment: "Another measure of the function is the number of local variables.  They
shouldn't exceed 5-10, or you're doing something wrong.  Re-think the
function, and split it into smaller pieces.  A human brain can
generally easily keep track of about 7 different things, anything more
and it gets confused." 

-https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Comment: So you know, `atoi()` already exists to convert strings into integers. I think that's what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

`sizeof(*str[1-2])` is the same as `sizeof(char)`. You are allocating a single char for both result buffers, which is clearly insufficient. Use `strlen(str[1-2]) + 1` this will give you a buffer equal to the number of chars in the string, plus one more for the null terminator.

Problem 2:

`getline()` allocates a buffer which you are expected to `free()` after you're done with it, you are not doing so which is effectively a memory leak. This is not the cause of your problem, but it bears mentioning. The same is true of all your `malloc()`'d memory.

Comment: Also, 'If *lineptr is set to NULL AND *n is set 0 before the call, then
       getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.'  Both calls to getline() reference 'sz' which, for the second call, will not be zero:(

Comment: Because the first argument is NULL, `sz` is ignored anyway, he could have just passed NULL instead of `&sz`

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of issues with this code.  Other people have pointed out the `malloc` problems, but on the whole it's unnecessarily complicated.  All the intermediate variables can be eliminated and `str1` and `str2` accessed directly.

To simplify things, I'm going to reduce this to just one input string, `str`.  If you want two, the code should be put into a function rather than copied.

The `for` + `sscanf` loops appear to be trying to iterate through `str` and checking that it contains only digits.  This is much better accomplished by walking through the character array until you hit the null character on the end.

```
for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
    ...do something with str[i]...
}
```

So checking that each character of input is a digit...

```
for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(!isdigit(str[i])){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid non-integer input '%c'\n", str[i]);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This will fail because `str`, being read from stdin, has a newline on the end.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to make a new attempt at it seeing as though I have so many complicated issues.